# youtube api search with vb6

Tags: vb6, youtube-api

i need to search youtube api with vb6, all i can find on-net is libraries for other popular languages

currently, am using the following url to search

```
URL = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" & TextBox1.Text &
"&suggested_categories=2%2C23%2C25&page=" & pagenum
```

an the i have to parse the page using regex, of which might fail if somthing changes in the search page

but i would prefer if i can do it with api, can anyone suggest a resource or solution

Comment: Forgive me, but what exactly is it your trying to do?

Comment: Have you thoguth about using the [actual search API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos) rather than parsing HTML?

Comment: @mattdonna search youtube using its v2 api with vb6

Comment: @Deanna i thought of that, but don't know how

Comment: @Smith: The same way you would request the HTML but use much simpler parsing. There are various other questions on SO about making HTTP requests in VB6.

Comment: @Deanna if i have to use api, then i have to do json and ouath  for vb6. it would take some time for me. do you have any lead for any of these? does the api support http query and xml response?

Comment: @Smith JOSN is simple structured text so relatively easily parsable. As for OAth, do you need to do user euthentication? You'd need to do the same for the HTML method. As for XML, have you read the link I gave? That's all I'd be doing.

Comment: i will use api but now am finding it difficult parsing the rss response. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220906/xpath-for-youtube-entry-search-result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not parse the web page using the MSHTML which comes with Internet Explorer? You need to add a reference to "Microsoft HTML Object Library". Weirdly, you have to instantiate an empty HTMLDocument object, and then create a new HTMLDocument object based on your URL by calling a method on the first object. But you have to keep the original object around, otherwise you keep on getting "Permission Denied" error messages. I still both of them into a UDT to ensure that they are kept in the same scope as each other.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type HtmlDoc
    Parent          As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Main            As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
End Type

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim URL
    Dim uHTMLDoc As HtmlDoc

    URL = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" & TextBox1.Text &  "&suggested_categories=2%2C23%2C25&page=" & pagenum 

    ' Source Code
    GetHTMLDocumentFromURL URL, uHTMLDoc
    Debug.Print uHTMLDoc.Main.documentElement.outerHTML

End Sub

Private Sub GetHTMLDocumentFromURL(ByRef the_sURL As String, ByRef the_uHTMLDoc As HtmlDoc)

    With the_uHTMLDoc

        Set .Parent = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

        Set .Main = .Parent.createDocumentFromUrl(the_sURL, vbNullString)

        ' Wait for the document to load completely.
        ' This is because the transfer is asynchronous.
        ' It is possible that this string might be different if you have another
        ' language than English for Internet Explorer on the
        ' machine where the code is executed.

        Do While .Main.readyState <> "complete"
            DoEvents
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

I don't know what type of parsing you want to do, but check out the various methods on the HTMLDocument class, such as GetElementById(), GetElementsByName(), and GetElementsByTagName(). Have a good look at the type library, and try a bit of experimentation to get the hang of it.

Comment: i need to exttract the url of each search result and its curresponding thumnail image. also can i check the progress like the webbrowser in your code with GetHTMLDocumentFromURL

Comment: Well, you need to find the enclosing element for all the search results, iterate through them, and find your way into the A element for the URL, and the IMG element for the thumbnail. The Watch Window will be your friend. As for progress - that depends on what you mean "progress". The readyState property of the document object can have four values: "uninitialized", "loading", "interactive" and "complete".

Comment: i meant currentprogress and maxprogress like the webbrowser control

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can't access the progress of the HTML document being loaded from these interfaces.