# xpath for youtube entry search result

Tags: xpath, vb6, youtube-api

i need help with the xpath query to extract the title text and **thumbnail url** of each **entry** in the following rss results

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>
<entry>
<title>LiveFit Augusta - "Gym Time"</title>
<media:group>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ig7CcLCR2n4/default.jpg'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ig7CcLCR2n4/mqdefault.jpg'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ig7CcLCR2n4/hqdefault.jpg'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ig7CcLCR2n4/1.jpg'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ig7CcLCR2n4/2.jpg'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ig7CcLCR2n4/3.jpg'/>
</media:group>
</entry>
<entry>
<title>LiveFit Augusta - "Everyday Joes &amp; Janes"</title>
<media:group>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/REhn9jjjV7Q/default.jpg'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/REhn9jjjV7Q/mqdefault.jpg'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/REhn9jjjV7Q/hqdefault.jpg'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/REhn9jjjV7Q/1.jpg'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/REhn9jjjV7Q/2.jpg'/>
<media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/REhn9jjjV7Q/3.jpg'/>
</media:group>
</entry>
</feed>
```

**the title**

< title type='text'>Evolution of Dance< /title>

or

< media:title type='plain'>Evolution of Dance< /media:title>

**thumbnail**

```
<media:thumbnail 
      url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/dMH0bHeiRNg/1.jpg' height='97' width='130' 
      time='00:01:30'/>
```

**EDIT**

here  is the code am using

```
Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument30
Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xmlEntryNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim ns As String
Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument30
ns = "xmlns:x='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'"
    xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", ns

If xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlText) = False Then
  Exit Function
End If

Set xmlEntryNodes = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("/feed/entry")
```

debug.print xmlEntryNodes.Length returns 0

Comment: What exactly do you need help with; where are you stuck at? FYI: "I need ..." is not typically the beginning of a question.

Comment: Why don't you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper i am just bot sure how to get the xpath expression, and i need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

ns = "xmlns:x='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'"

doc.SetProperty("SelectionNamespaces", ns)

**And then use an XPath expression like this**:

```
/*/x:entry/x:title[. = 'Evolution of Dance']
```

**and this**:

```
/*/x:entry/media:group/media:thumbnail[@url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/dMH0bHeiRNg/1.jpg']
```

**Learn more about the `SetProperty()` function here**:

**[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms756048(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms756048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

**Alternatively, if you don't want to register namespaces**, you may use less-readable expressions **like these**:

```
/*/*[name()='entry']/*[name()='title'][. = 'Evolution of Dance']
```

**and this**:

```
/*/*[name()='entry']
       /*[name()='media:group']
           /*[name()='media:thumbnail']
                 [@url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/dMH0bHeiRNg/1.jpg']
```

Comment: do i have to use namespaces? and if so what should be the actual value of http://myserver.com

Comment: @Smith, There was a copy/paste error (now fixed). It isn't myserver com -- it is the Atom namespaces. It is recommended to use namespaces so that the XPath is more readable. There is a way sometimes not to register namespaces (still the namespace-uris must be specified in the expression), but the result is difficult to read, understand and maintain. I will update this answer with the less readable expression.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

**title**

```
/feed/entry/title
```

**media:title**

```
/feed/entry/media:group/media:title
```

**thumbnail**

```
/feed/entry/media:group/media:thumbnail
```

Comment: pls look at my current rss text